# How to predict glm using new entry?

Tags: glm, predict

I have a data frame with next structure:

```
'data.frame':   29092 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ loan_status   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 ...
 $ loan_amnt     : int  5000 2400 10000 5000 3000 12000 9000 3000 10000 1000 ...
 $ grade         : Factor w/ 7 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 2 3 3 1 5 2 3 2 2 4 .
 $ home_ownership: Factor w/ 4 levels "MORTGAGE","OTHER",..: 4 4 4 4 4 3 4 4 4 4
 $ annual_inc    : num  24000 12252 49200 36000 48000 ...
 $ age           : int  33 31 24 39 24 28 22 22 28 22 ...
 $ ir_cat        : Factor w/ 5 levels "0-8","11-13.5",..: 4 5 2 5 5 2 2 4 4 3 .
 $ emp_cat       : Factor w/ 5 levels "0-15","15-30",..: 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

I run logistic regression with a goal of predicting loan_status, and I want to use predict for some new entry let's say:

```
loan_amnt = 4200
grade = C
home_ownership = MORTGAGE
annual_income = 32500
age = 31
ir_cat = "0-8"
emp_cat = "0-15"
```

Let's say i run

> glm(loan_status ~ ., data = loan_data, family = "binomial") -> glm1

and use predict:

> predict(glm1, newdata, type = "response")

My problem is what to add my new entry to newdata?

Comment: Well.. you want to predict Y, so you add X

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything. My question is, how can I input my new entry into predict function?

Comment: As a dataframe with a column for each X variable

Comment: I have no idea how. Can you provide me the code?

Comment: Did it. Thank you.